# How to pull the changes in Branch1 to Branch2 within the same repo?

Tags: github, git-bash, git-merge, upstream-branch

I am working on a Forked repo (xyz) of an Upstream repo (abc).
I created a branch (Branch1) and started working on it. Once Done, I raised a PR which looks like this:

```
Open: amol wants to merge 5 commits into abc:main from amol:Branch1
```

Now, while the PR is in review, I created a new branch (Branch2) and started working on different task.
My PR reviewers find some basic corrections and make those modifications to the PR accordingly.
I fetched those changes from upstream to my Local Branch1. I now want those changes to be updated in my current Branch2 as well.
What should I do?

I tried following commands on my local system using Git Bash.

```
git switch origin Main
git fetch upstream pull/#PR_ID/head:Branch1
git switch Branch1
```

By this I got those modifications done by the reviewers on my local system.

What should be the further commands to bring those modifications to my Branch 2?

Comment: Provided that both Branch1 and Branch2 have same "parent". You can merge branch1 into branch2.
If you have changes in the same file, you can first stash them, merge and un-stash

Comment: Hi Batman,
Thanks for the answer. For clarification, let me tell you the "parent" is not same for both the branches.